# Case outside Select Case Compile Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at coding and am looking for some help. I have a code here that is giving me the "case outside select case" error, but my case is inside "select case" and "end select" so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Sub codematch()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Select Case response = MsgBox("Is the cursor in the first cell of the column?", vbYesNo, "Code Finder")
Case condition1
    If response = 6 Then
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsm")
        Call wbk
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0)"
        Do Until ActiveCell = ""
        Call wbk.Close(False)
Case condition2
   If response = 7 Then
    response = MsgBox("Position the Cursor in the correct location and try again", vbOKOnly)
   End If
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Missing `End If` right before `Case condition2`

Comment: That `Select Case` isn't going to work even when you fix up the `If`.  (Well, it might "work", but I doubt if it will do what you think.)  The variable `response` (`0`?) will be compared to the result of your `MsgBox`.  If `response` matches the `MsgBox` then it will execute the first case if `condition1` evaluates to `True` or the second case if `condition1` is `False` and `condition2` is `True`.  If `response` isn't the same as `MsgBox`, then it will execute the first case if `condition1` evaluates to `False` or the second case if `condition1` is `True` and `condition2` is `False`.

Comment: you need to study the usage of `select case` statement. ... it works in a different way than you think  ........ if you knew what it does, you would not have the `if` statement inside the `case` statement

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is pointless frankly. Who cares where the user has the cursor.

```
Sub codematch()
dim target as range
set target = range("B1") 'or whever you want to start
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsm")
Target.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0)"

do 
   set target = target.offset(1,0)
   target.offset(-1,0).copy target
loop until target.offset(0,-1)=""
target.clear
target.parent.columns(target.column).cells.formula = 
_target.parent.columns(target.column).cells.value 'convert to values
wbk.close false
end sub
```

Is what I think you were trying to do